# Password check Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic-programming

So I'm trying to insert a div into another div, with Javascript, if 2 given passwords do not match up. However, everytime I try running this, it throws the error in the title of this post. I just want the div to disappear if the 2 passwords match.

```
function passwordMismatchError(){
    var pwrd1 = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var pwrd2 = document.getElementById('password-confirmation').value;
    if(pwrd1 != pwrd2){
        // If there is an error box already
        if(document.getElementById("password-mismatch-error")){
            return;
        }
        // If there isn't an error box
        else{
            errcount++;
            var innerdiv = document.createElement('div');
            innerdiv.setAttribute("id", "password-mismatch-error");
            innerdiv.innerHTML = "<p>ERROR: Passwords don't match.</p>";
            (document.getElementById("error-display")).appendChild(innerdiv);
        }
    }
    else{
        // If the passwords match
        errcount--;
        var innerdiv = document.getElementById("password-mismatch-error");
        console.log(innerdiv);
        innerdiv.parentNode.removeChild(innerdiv);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your outer `else` statement, `#password-mismatch-error` is never added to the DOM, so `innerdiv` will be undefined. Thus you can't access its `parentNode`.

To resolve this, simply check that the element exists before trying to remove its parent with `if(document.getElementById("password-mismatch-error"))`:

```
function passwordMismatchError(){
    var pwrd1 = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var pwrd2 = document.getElementById('password-confirmation').value;
    if(pwrd1 != pwrd2){
        // If there is an error box already
        if(document.getElementById("password-mismatch-error")) {
            return;
        }
        // If there isn't an error box
        else{
            errcount++;
            var innerdiv = document.createElement('div');
            innerdiv.setAttribute("id", "password-mismatch-error");
            innerdiv.innerHTML = "<p>ERROR: Passwords don't match.</p>";
            (document.getElementById("error-display")).appendChild(innerdiv);
        }
    }
    else{
        // If the passwords match
        errcount--;
        // Ensure the error message actually exists in the DOM
        if(document.getElementById("password-mismatch-error")) {
            var innerdiv = document.getElementById("password-mismatch-error");
            console.log(innerdiv);
            innerdiv.parentNode.removeChild(innerdiv);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I tried that @obsidian-age in which the error is gone, but it's still not getting rid of the div thats displaying with the "password-mismatch-error" id. /: